# How to receive eventbus events when Activity is in the background

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-notifications, greenrobot-eventbus

I want to get notification message using Firebase Notification service. I'm sending message from Firebase, it is ok.

I want to get this notification if user run in `MainActivity` also I want to show pop-up using dialog.

If user run other activities for example `SettingActivity` or `ProfileActivity`, notification handle anyway and user run `MainActivity` pop-up appear suddenly.

To do this I'm using Greenbot Eventbus. When I'm inside `MainActivity` and  notification comes It appears so it is ok. But When I'm inside another `Activity` notification not coming.

How to handle this message until come `MainActivity`?

```
public class NotificationService  extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "evenBus" ;

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);


        Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived");
        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            // do nothing if Notification message is received
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new NotificationEvent(body));
        }
    }
}
```

MainActiviy

```
@Override
    protected void onResume(){
       EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
 }

// This method will be called when a MessageEvent is posted (in the UI thread for Toast)
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onMessageEvent(NotificationEvent event) {
    Log.v("onMessageEvent","Run");
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, event.getBody(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    alertSendActivity("title",event.getBody());
}

@TargetApi(11)
protected void alertSendActivity(final String title,final String data) {
    alt = new AlertDialog.Builder(this,
            AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT).create();
    alt.setTitle(title);
    alt.setMessage(data);
    alt.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    alt.setCancelable(false);
    alt.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, getString(R.string.ok),
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    alt.dismiss();
                }
            });

    alt.show();
}

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
     EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're calling `unregister()` in `onStop()`, so you do not receive events when `MainActivity` is in the background.

To receive events even when the `Activity` is in the background, you should register in `onCreate()` and unregister in `onDestroy()` (rather than in `onResume()`/`onStop()`).

Move the following line to `onCreate()`:

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
```

And this one to `onDestroy()`:

```
EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
```

Also check out the [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html).

Comment: You saved my Time. Thank you !!

Comment: No solution is as perfect as compared to this one